# Firestore data is retrieved on recyclerview is not showing utill i click on EditText search bar on fragment

Tags: firebase, android-fragments, search, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored all my data on firebase cloud firestore. Trying to show those on recyclerView as well as made that filterable. But when i am on the fragment where recycleView is implemented nothing is showing until i click the EditText search bar. For understanding the problem Click here https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzMmT.jpg to watch the video.

**MarketFragment.java**

```
package com.example.farmersapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MarketFragment extends Fragment {

  private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
  private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
  private FloatingActionButton floatingAddNewItemButton;

  private String mParam1;
  private String mParam2;

  RecyclerView marketRecyleView;
  ListAdapter_Market marketListAdapter;
  ArrayList<productsListOfMarketFirestore> mData;
  ConstraintLayout rootLayout;
  EditText searchInput;
  CharSequence search = "";
  FirestoreRecyclerOptions<productsListOfMarketFirestore> options;

  AlternateListAdapter_Market adapter;

  private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  private CollectionReference productsOfMarketCollectionRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("products_of_market");

  public MarketFragment() {
  }

  public static MarketFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MarketFragment fragment = new MarketFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
      mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
      mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
  }
  productsListOfMarketFirestore[] item = new productsListOfMarketFirestore[100];

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View contentView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_market, container, false);

    floatingAddNewItemButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    marketRecyleView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.market_rv);
    rootLayout = contentView.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    searchInput = contentView.findViewById(R.id.search_input);
    mData = new ArrayList<>();


    searchInput.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_input_style);
    rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


   getDataToArray();
    setUpRecyclerViewManual();
    searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


          adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
          search = s;
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


      }
    });

      Log.d("checked","i am here");
      floatingAddNewItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Fragment fragment = new AddNewItemFragment();
          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

          fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
          fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
      });
    return contentView;
  }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

  private void getDataToArray() {
    productsOfMarketCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
          Log.d("checked", "database is empty");
        } else {
          List<productsListOfMarketFirestore> data = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(productsListOfMarketFirestore.class);

          mData.addAll(data);
          Log.d("checked success:", "ok " + mData);
        }


      }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("checked", "data load failed");
      }
    });


  }
  private void setUpRecyclerViewManual() {
    marketRecyleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    adapter = new AlternateListAdapter_Market(mData,this.getContext());
    marketRecyleView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("checked","adapter called");

    marketRecyleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


  }

}
```

**AlternateListAdapter_Market.java**

```
package com.example.farmersapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlternateListAdapter_Market extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlternateListAdapter_Market.AlternateListHolder_Market> implements Filterable {

     List<productsListOfMarketFirestore>filterList;
     List<productsListOfMarketFirestore>mainList;
     Context mContext;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlternateListHolder_Market onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout;

        layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.customlist_item_market, parent, false);
        return new AlternateListHolder_Market(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AlternateListHolder_Market holder, int position) {

        productsListOfMarketFirestore curretItem = filterList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.fade_transition_animation));
        holder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.fade_scale_animation));

        holder.textView_productId.setText(curretItem.getProductId());
        holder.textView_price.setText(curretItem.getProductPrice());
        holder.textView_title.setText(curretItem.getProductTitle());
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://app-31e12.appspot.com/user_image1/").child(curretItem.getProductId() + ".jpg");
        try {
            final File file = File.createTempFile("image", "jpg");
            storageReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return filteredData;
    }
    private   Filter filteredData= new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<productsListOfMarketFirestore> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filterList = mainList;
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (productsListOfMarketFirestore item : mainList) {
                    if (item.getProductTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        Log.d("checked","productTitle check "+item.getProductTitle());
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
                filterList = filteredList;

            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filterList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filterList =(List<productsListOfMarketFirestore>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    class AlternateListHolder_Market extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView_title;
        TextView textView_price,textView_productId;
        RelativeLayout container;

        public AlternateListHolder_Market(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_item_market);
            textView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_title_market);
            textView_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_price);
            textView_productId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productId);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_container_market);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Fragment itemFragment = MarketItemDetails.newInstance("", "");
                    if (itemFragment != null) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("productId", textView_productId.getText().toString());
                        itemFragment.setArguments(args);
                        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, itemFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("error", "null exception");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }

    AlternateListAdapter_Market(List<productsListOfMarketFirestore > exampleList,Context Context) {
        this.filterList = exampleList;
        this.mainList = exampleList;
        this.mContext = Context;
    }


public void setFilterList(List<productsListOfMarketFirestore> mList)
{
    this.filterList = mList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

**productsListOfMarketFirestore.java**

```
package com.example.farmersapp;

public class productsListOfMarketFirestore  {

    String productArea,productCategory,productCondition,productDescription;
    String productId,productOwner,productPrice,productRegion,productTitle;

    public productsListOfMarketFirestore() {
    }

    public productsListOfMarketFirestore(String productArea, String productCategory, String productCondition, String productDescription, String productId, String productOwner, String productPrice, String productRegion, String productTitle) {
        this.productArea = productArea;
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
        this.productCondition = productCondition;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productOwner = productOwner;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.productRegion = productRegion;
        this.productTitle = productTitle;
    }

    public String getProductArea() {
        return productArea;
    }

    public String getProductCategory() {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public String getProductCondition() {
        return productCondition;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getProductOwner() {
        return productOwner;
    }

    public String getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductRegion() {
        return productRegion;
    }

    public String getProductTitle() {
        return productTitle;
    }
}
```

**fragment_market.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/market_rv"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="672dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_input"
        tools:listitem="@layout/customlist_item_market" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#0979D3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.915"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.845" />

    <EditText
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_gray_24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
        android:hint="search"
        android:background="@drawable/search_input_style"
        android:id="@+id/search_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**customlist_item_market.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_container_market"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="136dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@color/card_bg_color"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView_item_title_market"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:text="Simple Title Text "
            android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_price"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_productId"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="113dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="TextView" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_item_market"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="137dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone help please?... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do you see these 2 lines in `setUpRecyclerViewManual()`**

```
........
adapter = new AlternateListAdapter_Market(mData,this.getContext());
marketRecyleView.setAdapter(adapter);
........
```

**Move them here:**

```
  private void getDataToArray() {
    productsOfMarketCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
          Log.d("checked", "database is empty");
        } else {
          List<productsListOfMarketFirestore> data = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(productsListOfMarketFirestore.class);

          //here.........
          adapter = new AlternateListAdapter_Market(data,this.getContext());
          marketRecyleView.setAdapter(adapter);

          Log.d("checked success:", "ok " + mData);
        }
        ..........
        ..........
```

**Also reverse the calling order in `fragment`**

```
//call this first 
setUpRecyclerViewManual();

//then call this
getDataToArray();
```

Comment: It's working properly now. But why it's working what is basic concept behind this?

Comment: Okay the concept here is that the data listener of firebase takes time to invoke, and previously you are setting the adapter before data is received, so to be safe create the adapter when the data is received in the listener.